Graalvm Serialization of java.lang.Integer?
I'm working on getting our Spring Boot application working with Graalvm inside a docker container.
I've been going through the process of adding classes to the reflection-config.json and serialization-config.json files and am now getting issues with basic core Java classes like Number, Integer, and Boolean.
For instance,
    2024-12-05T08:07:38.062Z ERROR 1 --- [wfprev] [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]      : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/wfprev-api] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed: com.oracle.svm.core.jdk.UnsupportedFeatureError: SerializationConstructorAccessor class not found for declaringClass: java.lang.Integer (targetConstructorClass: java.lang.Object). Usually adding java.lang.Integer to serialization-config.json fixes the problem.] 

with root cause
com.oracle.svm.core.jdk.UnsupportedFeatureError: SerializationConstructorAccessor class not found for declaringClass: java.lang.Integer (targetConstructorClass: java.lang.Object). Usually adding java.lang.Integer to serialization-config.json fixes the problem.

Surely I don't need to add every single java class to these config files, do I?  What am I doing wrong?
Here's my serialization-config.json so far:
[
  { "name": "org.springframework.hateoas.RepresentationModel"},
  { "name": "org.springframework.hateoas.Link"},
  { "name": "org.springframework.hateoas.Links"},
  { "name": "java.util.Date"},
  { "name": "java.sql.Timestamp" },
  { "name": "java.lang.Number" },
  { "name": "java.lang.Integer" },
  { "name": "java.lang.Boolean" },
  { "name": "java.math.BigDecimal" }

]

Here's my Dockerfile in case it helps
FROM ghcr.io/graalvm/graalvm-community:21 AS builder

# Define build argument and set it as environment variable
ARG MAVEN_SETTINGS_FILE=settings.xml

ENV MAVEN_SETTINGS_FILE=${MAVEN_SETTINGS_FILE}

# The environment variables from .env are automatically available here
# We don't need the ARG declarations anymore since we're using the env file

WORKDIR /app

# Copy maven settings first
COPY mvn_settings/${MAVEN_SETTINGS_FILE} /root/.m2/settings.xml

# Copy rest of the application
COPY . /app

# Make mvnw executable
RUN chmod +x mvnw

# Build the native image using settings.xml
RUN ./mvnw -s mvn_settings/${MAVEN_SETTINGS_FILE} -Pnative native:compile -DskipTests

# Runtime stage
FROM ubuntu:22.04

# Install curl for healthcheck and debugging
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libc6 \
    libstdc++6 \
    curl \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Copy the native executable from builder stage
COPY --from=builder /app/target/wfprev-api /

# Expose the port your application uses
EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT ["/wfprev-api"]```


If you something in your application serializes something containing java.lang.Integers, you need to include it in the serialization config. What about that would be surprising?

Also you might be able to use the native image agent to figure out what you need to include.
